# How `Cache-Control` header of a server affects TestCafe server

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browser-automation

I have always used `http-server` (npm package) to serve my static files with their `-c-1` flag to disable caching. But it seems like TestCafe doesn't like that. It can see the webpage you are serving only for the first test, but it can't access it for the rest. Does anyone know why?

[Looking at http-server code](https://github.com/http-party/http-server/blob/master/lib/http-server.js#L77), you can see that if you set the cache value to `-1` it will set the header as `'no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate'`. How does that affect TestCafe server?

Comment: This header shouldn't lead to any incorrect TestCafe behavior. Could you describe this effect in greater detail? If you have a simple project and a set of certain steps to reproduce the problem, you can create an issue in the [TestCafe GitHub repository](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?template=bug-report.md).

Comment: Here is the repo: https://github.com/ajmeyghani/toaster. I'll make the issue in a bit also.

Comment: Thank you for providing your sample repo. Since this behavior looks like an issue, please submit a bug report and fill in all the required fields including the reproduction steps.